# Apache in Ampps doen's start after installing Laravel (Mac)

Tags: php, apache, laravel, ampps

I've been using Ampps with no problem until I installed Laravel.

Once I did, Apache in Ampps doesn't start. I suppose it's a conflict on port 80 but I don't know how to solve it.

When I execute:

```
sudo /Applications/AMPPS/apache/bin/httpd
```

I get:

```
(48)Address already in use: AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address [::]:80
(48)Address already in use: AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address 0.0.0.0:80
no listening sockets available, shutting down
AH00015: Unable to open logs
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it!

When you serve apache through laravel:

```
php artisan serve
```

Ctrl + C doesn't kill. You need to kill it through:

```
apachectl stop
```

or
    /etc/init.d/http stop

Hope someone finds this useful

Answer (score 1):

This was exactly what happened to me and @anexo [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36533776/1777938) solved the issue.
For some reasons though, the Terminal requires a root access.
Incase anyone have issue with that, just use:

```
sudo apachectl stop
```

This would prompt for your password, after which it would complete the operation.

NB: I couldn't add this as comment to @anexo answer due to low rep.